# Check if back key was pressed in android?

Tags: java, android, back-button

Say I'm on my main activity and I start a new activity

```
MainActivity > NewActivity
```

And from `NewActivity` I press the back key

```
MainActivity < NewActivity
```

I want `MainActivity` to do something if it's being displayed after `NewActivity` is closed, but not when `MainActivity` is run normally, such as when first running the application. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

- You can just set a flag in `MainActivity` when it fires up `NewActivity`.
- You can call `startActivityForResult` from `MainActivity` and arrange for `NewActivity` to set a result, which you will receive in `MainActivity.onActivityResult()` when `NewActivity` finishes.

Answer (score 24):

```java
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

@Update. If you want to be notified when NewActivity is finished, you have to start it by startActivityForResult(Intent, requestCode). Then, you must override onActivityResult() on MainActivity. Check the requestcode parameter here, if the return code equals the submit code (when you start childActivity), put some code to do your business.

```
int MYCODE=1000;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Result OK.d.
    if (requestCode == MYCODE) {
        // do something good
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just listen if the back button is pressed?

Comment: If you want to listen to the back button only, use the first snipped codes.

Comment: onKeyDown doesn't get called if, you press the back button and soft keyboard is visible.

Answer (score 14):

I try the below method to detect the back button pressed on the action bar in activity by the first method and the second one is used to detecting the mobile hardware button back or kill activity button.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can override onBackPressed() method in NewActivity which will detect when back button is pressed. And then to inform the MainActivity about it, you can send a boolean flag in a bundle so that MainActivity detects that its opening after NewActivity.

In NewActivity:

```
       @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
                boolean fromNewActivity=true;

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundleObj = new Bundle();
        bundleObj.putString("fromNewActivity", Boolean.toString(fromNewActivity));
        mainIntent.putExtras(bundleObj);
        startActivityForResult(mainIntent, 0);
           }
```

In MainActivity in onCreate() method :

```
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       boolean fromNewActivity =Boolean.parseBoolean( extras.getString("fromNewActivity"));
```

Now you can check if the MainActivity is opened after NewActivity or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you start `NewActivity` you need to use `startActivityForResult` and use a valid `requestId`. Such `requestId` will be passed back to you to `onActivityResult` once `NewActivity` finishes.