# Is there a way to exploite the buttom navigation bar in my mobile (previous,home) in my android app so that i don't have to create a cutomized one

Tags: android, navigation

I'm setting a new android app, and I want to exploit the bottom navigation bar in my phone (previous,home) so that i don't have to create a customized one, I want to know if it is possible to set an `onClickEvent` on these buttons

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182703/check-if-back-key-was-pressed-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle both button separately.

1. For hardware back button (Previous) you have to `override` `onBackPress` method in your `Activity` class. So, you will get the back press event you can change the behavior of back button if you don't want back event just remove `super.onBackPress()`. If you want to do this from fragment you just need to add your logic like you can get current fragment instance from `FragmentManager` like below and call fragment method what ever you want to do on that fragment.

```
    \\ To get current fragment 
    \\ NOTE: I add back stack name as class name.
    public static Fragment getCurrentFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backStackEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
            String tag = backStackEntry.getName();
            return fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // enter code here
        super.onBackPressed(); // Remove this line if you don't want to go back.
    }
```

1. For home button handling you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956263/3932166) answer or [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/06/02/override-hardware-home-button-android-listen-home-button-click-android/) post.

Please comment me if you have more questions.